# Show login page that fills the body

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, angularjs-routing

in angularjs (1.3) and bootstrap 3 (with customized classes) i have the following index structure:

```
<html ng-app="myApp">
...
<body>
   <main class="page-content container">
       <div ng-include src="'Views/Partials/Navbar.html'"></div>
       <div ng-include src="'Views/Partials/Sidebar.html'"></div>

       <div class="page-inner">
           <div ng-view>
           </div>
       </div>
   </main>
</body>
...
</html>
```

So i have a boxed layout with navigation sidebar and a content div where i show the content page using the $routeProvider.

[image]

Now I want to show a login page that fills the entire window, so that its not inside the page-inner div.

How can i achieve it with angular? Because the ng-view is inside the page-inner div and i want inject my html page at the body level.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can use `ng-hide` to hide the navbar/sidebar and `ng-class` to  apply different `css` to your content depending on current location(*login or site content*) using `$location.url()`.

**Something like :**

```
<html ng-app="myApp">
...
<body>
   <main class="page-content container">
       <div ng-show="show.navbar" ng-include src="'Views/Partials/Navbar.html'"></div>
       <div ng-show="show.sidebar" ng-include src="'Views/Partials/Sidebar.html'"></div>

       <div ng-class="{{css.innerContent}}">
           <div ng-view>
           </div>
       </div>
   </main>
</body>
...
</html>
```

**controller :**

```
//show navbar/sidebar by default
$scope.show = {
   navbar : true,
   sidebar : true 
}
//default values for css class
$scope.css = {
    innerContent : "page-inner" 
}
//check current location and assign new values
if( $location.url() == "/login"){
    $scope.show.navbar = false;
    $scope.show.sidebar = false;
    $scope.css.innerContent = "login-inner"
}
```

**css :**

```
 //example of css
.page-inner{
    width:50%;
}
.login-inner{
    width:100%;
}
```